# salto com lista circular

Tags: c

Boa noite pessoal, estou precisando de ajuda com um trabalho.

Seguinte:

O programa deve receber 3 variáveis de entrada

m= número total de pessoas, p= posição da pessoa escolhida, n= numero de saltos.

a pessoa que está na posição onde o salto cai morre, o programa deve rodar até ter apenas 1 sobrevivente.

no final deve ser exibido MORTO e o número do sobrevivente caso o salto caia na posição escolhida e VIVO caso não caia.

Fiz um código mas não está totalmente certo, o problema é que o programa deve continuar rodando até ter apenas um sobrevivente, e a cada rodada deve ser eliminado os numeros que 'morrem', não estou conseguindo fazer isso só com contador e vetor. Pensei em implementar com uma lista circular mas não sei como fazer, alguem pode ajudar?

Caso seja necessário estou uma imagem para melhor entendimento.

[clique aqui para ver imagem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlvwH.png)

int main (){

```
int m, p, n,i, morre, score,sobrevive, j=0;

scanf("%d %d %d",&m , &p, &n);

int vet[m];
    for(i=1;i<=m;i++){
        vet[i]=i;
    }
    morre=vet[n+1];
    i=1;
    for(j=0;j<m;j++){
            if(i>m){
                i=i-m;
                morre = vet[i];
            }
            if(morre==p){
                score=1;
                sobrevive=vet[i--]; 
            }
            i=i+n;
            morre = vet[i];     
        }

if(score==1){
    printf("MORTO \n");
}else{
    printf("VIVO");
}
```

}

Comment: Talvez seja melhor declarar um vetor de m posições, que represente se a pessoa está morta ou viva, e inicializa-lo com todas vivas. Pule, de forma circular, n vivas e marque como morta. Não tem muito sentido inicializar o vetor com o próprio índice. Fique em um loop enquanto tiver mais de uma viva. Avalie se sempre existirá uma solução ou pode chegar a uma situação insolúvel.

Comment: sim, mas eu não sei como fazer o vetor parar quando estiver apenas uma viva, não sei qual condição colocar, e não sei como fazer ele voltar ao começo do indice quando chegar no ultimo numero do indice e não sei como fazer ele não contar os que estão mortos é nisso que eu preciso de ajuda

Comment: Você pode definir um contador inicializando-o com o número total de pessoas e a cada morte vai decrementando 1 até chegar a 1.

Comment: sim eu tentei isso mas não funcionou totalmente em alguns casos de teste não bateu, acabei implementando outro codigo com lista mas obrigada pela ajuda

Answer (score 0):

Veja se é isto o que deseja:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define VIVO 0
#define MORTO 1
int main (){
    int m, p, n, i, sobreviventes, pos, j, k, l;
    scanf("%d %d %d",&m , &p, &n);
    int vet[m];
    for(i=0; i<m; i++){
        vet[i] = VIVO;
    }
    sobreviventes = m;
    pos = p - 1;
    while (sobreviventes > 1) {
        j=0;
        k = pos;
        while (j < n) {
            k %= m;
            if (vet[k] == VIVO)
                j++;
            k++;
        }
        vet[--k] = MORTO;
        sobreviventes--;
        pos = k;
        printf("\nSobreviventes: %d\n", sobreviventes);
        for (l=0; l<m; l++)
            printf("\t%d: %d", l, vet[l]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```